# What is the best way to design database table for if conditional based information

Tags: database, database-design

I need to develop a simple database application. A table to store a patient social history answering following question,

Do you smoke? If yes, how many cigarettes per day?**__How many years?_**
Do you drink alcohol?**__** If yes, how many alcoholic beverages per week?***_***
Do you use drugs?***_****If yes, what kind?*__*_*_*How often?*__*_*___
etc. 
I can have table column for every answer. As there are if then else conditionals, I would like to know, what will be the best way  to design table for this type of scenario.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want to do here is try and generalize the kind of questions you're asking. What stands out for me is that you're asking questions about *habits*, or a kind of repetitive behavior.

Abstract out your question: What kind of habit is it (Smoking? Drinking? Drug 1, Drug 2, Drug 3)? How frequently do you indulge this habit? Do you do it daily, weekly, monthly, yearly ? If you do it daily, how many times a day? How many times a week/month/year?

This means you can have a table describing generic 'habits', where each row represents a patient's answers regarding a specific habit, and each column represents a specific piece of data that the patient has answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking with a flat row for "survey_responses" or similar rather than a meta setup then just let the follow up questions be NULL. you're application should handle validations etc.